Why is this site called Cryptography and not Cryptology?
Cryptography is the study of encryption. Cryptology is the study of both encryption and decryption/cryptanalysis. Is cryptanalysis out of scope here?

Cryptography is generally considered a synonym of cryptology nowadays. Cryptology would of course be the better name if you look at the etymology of the terms, although you could argue that "kryptos" also doesn't cover the contents, as "hidden" hardly seems to cover hashes and random number generation.
Language doesn't evolve using logical reasoning; it contains many words that just kind-a stuck. Many terms - if not most terms - have changed meaning during the lifetime of a language; we would not even be able to understand persons that spoke old English.

Perhaps to some extent but I would say that misinformed usage corrupts language rather than changes it.  By naming something cryptography rather than cryptology it does still show a tiny smidgen of amateurism. Another pet peeve of mine is when people use "begs the question" to mean "raises the question". Soon we will all have forgotten what "begging the question" really means.

I don't disagree with you but we are not in the driving seat, we can just try and and indicate the direction we should be going (for terms that haven't solidified themselves in the jargon).

Well I agree with that and I think we could start by renaming the site to Cryptology, as it should be properly called.

Better naming could be the Adversary Theory. It was suggested but not captured enough attention.

@Frank That was more of a generic remark when it comes to cryptographic terms that haven't solidified yet. I don't think that the term cryptography is a moving target anymore; you cannot steer something that has come to a halt. We now use the term "encryption" if we talk about performing "hidden writing" and ciphertext for the "writing" itself - there is no need for "cryptography" to maintain the literal meaning anymore.
